# When is glFlush called too often?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an application that issues about 100 drawcalls per frame, each with an individual VBO. The VBOs are uploaded via `glBufferData` in a separate thread has has gl context resource sharing. The render thread tests buffer upload state via `glClientWaitSync`.

Now my question:

According to the documentation `glClientWaitSync` and `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` cause a flush at every call, right? This would mean that for every not yet finished `glBufferData` in the upload thread I would have dozens of flushes in the render thread right? What impact on performance would it have if thus, in the worst case, I practically issue a flush before every drawcall?

Comment: "*each with an individual VBO*" Stop doing that. Use a single buffer, not a bunch of tiny ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` has changed from its original specification.

In the original, the use of that bit was the equivalent of issuing a `glFlush` before doing the wait.

However, GL 4.5 changed the wording. Now, it is the equivalent of *having performed* a flush immediately after you submitted that sync object. That is, instead of doing a flush relative to the current stream, it works as if you had flushed after submitting the sync. Thus, repeated use does not mean repeatedly flushing.

You can get the equivalent behavior of course by manually issuing a flush after you submit the sync object, then not using `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` when you wait for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does OpenGL ES 3.1 feature the old or new behavior?